# What is a urllib code equivalent for a mechanize submit() method?

Tags: python, mechanize, urllib

Im not sure the Title is clear enough so this is whats up:

I've started learning Python about 3 weeks ago, and recently I gave myself a task - to login to a website and then read specific page, and post the comment in the same page, all using Python scrypt. I did a search in documentation and I found urllib, urllib2 and cookielib modules to be what I was looking for. So I came up with this code:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
import re

url_page = 'http://www.example.net/page/'
url_login = 'http://www.example.net/login.php'
url_post = 'http://www.example.net/post.php'

def main():

    #login data
    username = 'user1'
    password = 'user1'

    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

    login_data = urllib.urlencode({'j_user' : username, 'j_pass' : password})
    opener.open(url_login, login_data)

    opener.open(url_page)    

    #comment is in string
    s = "abcd"

    #post data
    post_data = urllib.urlencode({'com' : s})
    opener.open(url_post, post_data)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

First part (login) works fine, I get logged into site and I can get the page. But nothing happens - it fails to post the comment. 
Then, I found on this site that `mechanize` module is the best solution for web browsing. So, I found this script and adapted it for my purpose:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
import urllib
import re

#required addresses
url_page = 'http://www.example.net/page/'

def main():
    br = mechanize.Browser() 
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)

    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)

    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    r = br.open(url_page)

    #selecting form
    br.select_form(nr=2)
    #setting inputs 
    br.form['j_user'] = 'user1'
    br.form['j_pass'] = 'user1'

    #login
    r = br.submit()

    r = br.open(url_page)

    s = "abcd"

    #posting
    br.select_form(nr=4)
    br.form['com'] = s
    br.submit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the script runs perfect - it posts the comment.

So my question is - where is the problem with first script? Why the posting comment in first script is not giving the results? Is it missing something?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I fear, I can't help you without knowing the page you are trying to post to. The problem is, that mechanize uses its own logic for form selecting (`br.select_form`). Python obviously doesn't do that. It can be, that the form on the page has some hidden input fields (like CSFR token) which are required for the correct response processing. What status code does the pure python script return?

Comment: @DimitriVorona  - Thanks for your replay. There is no hidden fields in the page, only 'submit' and 'text' fields. After submitting with pure Python script I get page with 'Error' message which is equal to what I get if I just try to follow the 'http://www.example.net/post.php' link from the webpage source code. Otherwise, it should return page with message like 'posting successful' (the one that mechanize submit() returns). I'm not sure hot to check status code in Python, but the script runs complete code with no errors.

Comment: To check status code use `r = opener.openurl(url); print r.code`. It sounds to me like a missing POST argument issue, but I might be wrong. Try to encode every form field into the `post_data` and see if it helps. Also, if you have access to the server's code, look how it handles the post data. Looking into the POST statement you browser send (can be done with firebug etc) might be helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at mechanize source shows me that ultimately mechanize uses urllib2.Request instance and calls its add_data member. The docs say that Request sets a User-Agent. is it possible your web server is rejecting the post do to lack of or invalid User-Agent?

There is a nice tutorial on doing what you want in an old PyMOTW post. http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urllib2/  It links to valuable resources like Michael Foord's missing manual. http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml

It looks like the HttpHandler adds a header of  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded on the request. You could try adding it in your first case. It also sets the Content-Length header.

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/457c0c9c7893/Lib/urllib2.py#l1112

```
post_data = urllib.urlencode({'com' : s})
post_headers_and_data = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nContent-Length: {0}\n\n{1}".format(len(post_data), post_data)
opener.open(url_post, post_headers_and_data)
```

Comment: That just may be the case.  Currently, I'm in a lack of a free time due to my college assignments, so this problem is not in the first plan. Anyway, thank you for taking some time to answer and post this useful links I'll sure check out.